# Trying to add a warning role when a user says something

Tags: python, discord, python-3.6, discord.py

<s>Title pretty much says it all, I'm trying add the roles 'Warning 1' or 'Warning 2' when a user says something that is contained within `bannedWords`. I've seen people use `await bot.add_roles()` and just `await add_roles()` but both of those return an error. They give an `AttributeError` and `NameError` respectively. Am I missing an import or is there something that I did wrong?</s> Fixed

<s>Alright so I found the answer to my first problem but am now getting a `discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10011): Unknown Role` error.</s>

Discord was trying to add the role `message.author` when using `await message.author.add_roles(message.author,role,reason='Reason: Used \'%s\' in \'%s\ , on %s/%s/%s (day,month,year) at %s' % (word, str(message.channel),day,month,year,time))` removing the second `message.author` fixes this, so it should be:

```
await message.author.add_roles(role,reason='Reason: Used \'%s\' in \'%s\ , on %s/%s/%s (day,month,year) at %s' % (word, str(message.channel),day,month,year,time))
```

Attribute Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Productive\Programming Projects\Python 3\Other\MyBot\bot.py", line 41, in on_message
    await bot.add_roles(message.author,role,reason='Reason: Used \'%s\' in \'%s\ , on %s/%s/%s (day,month,year) at %s' % (word, str(message.channel),day,month,year,time))
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'add_roles'
```

NameError:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Productive\Programming Projects\Python 3\Other\MyBot\bot.py", line 41, in on_message
    await add_roles(message.author,role,reason='Reason: Used \'%s\' in \'%s\ , on %s/%s/%s (day,month,year) at %s' % (word, str(message.channel),day,month,year,time))
NameError: name 'add_roles' is not defined
```

All Relevant Code

```py
import discord;from discord.utils import get
from datetime import datetime
bot=discord.Client()

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in')
    print('Username: %s' % (bot.user.name))
    print('Userid: %s' % (bot.user.id))

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id == bot.user.id:
        return
    # delete messages with banned words
    bannedWords=['chink','dyke','fag','ook','molest','nig','rape','retard','spic','zipperhead','tranny']
    if str(message.channel)!='no-rules-lol':
        for word in bannedWords:
            if word in message.content.lower():
                await message.channel.send('{0.author.mention}, you have used a word that is black-listed please read <#754763230169006210> to get a full list of black-listed words'.format(message))
                await message.delete()

                #guild=bot.get_guild(id=754064902611796008)
                #role=discord.utils.get(guild.roles,name='Warning 1')
                #member=guild.get_member(message.author.id)
                # get the time the warning was applied.
                currentTime,_=str(datetime.now()).split('.')
                date,time=currentTime.split(' ')
                year,month,day=date.split('-')
                print('message = ' + str(message))
                role=get(message.guild.roles,name="Warning 1")
                await message.author.add_roles(message.author,role,reason='Reason: Used \'%s\' in \'%s\ , on %s/%s/%s (day,month,year) at %s' % (word, str(message.channel),day,month,year,time))

bot.run(Token)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add_roles is a Member object method: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=add_roles#discord.Member.add_roles

the [Message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#message) object from [on_message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message) should contain a Member object in message.author, so you would do:

```py
await message.author.add_roles(role, reason='Reason: Used \'%s\' in \'%s\ , on %s/%s/%s (day,month,year) at %s' % (word, str(message.channel),day,month,year,time))
```

Comment: Yea not too long after posting it I tried message.author and it worked fine but now I'm getting a `discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10011): Unknown Role` error

Comment: Make sure you have a role named `Warning 1`, however I suggest using the role ID instead of the name.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I've done this by calling `add_roles` on the `author` of the message.  In your case, it would be like this:

```
await message.author.add_roles(role,reason='Reason: Used \'%s\' in \'%s\ , on %s/%s/%s (day,month,year) at %s' % (word, str(message.channel),day,month,year,time)
```

I don't think I included a `reason` argument, so I'm not sure if this form will take that argument, but if the other forms do, I would think it would.

Comment: It should be working with `reason` but I'm now getting a `discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10011): Unknown Role` error instead.

Comment: Your utils.get isn't returning a role, make sure you have a role named `Warning 1`, however I recommend using role IDs instead of names.

Comment: I ended up finding the reason of my problem (I had `message.author` in `add_roles()` so it was trying to add the author of the message as a role and I was using the name instead of an id so I can use it on my testing server and the actual server I use.